# Uncaught SyntaxError - Get the value of an object that is in another object

Tags: javascript, json

Can someone please explain what is wrong with my below javascript code:

```
var testData = '{"test":"testvalue", "test2":"{"boxcolor":"bg-white", "iconcolor":"bg-aqua"}"}';

testFunction(testData);

function testFunction(data)
{
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(obj.test2.boxcolor);
}
```

Here is the console error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token b

I am wanting to get the value of an object, where the object is nested in another object.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if the innear object is parsed in the primary parse operation, can u remove the innear object qoutes?

Comment: Or try to JSON.parse(obj.test2) before referencing boxcolor..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering how you ever came up with that JSON string.

```
{"test":"testvalue", "test2":"{"boxcolor":"bg-white", "iconcolor":"bg-aqua"}"}
                             ^                                              ^
```

Here's the fixed code:

```js
var testData = '{"test":"testvalue", "test2":{"boxcolor":"bg-white", "iconcolor":"bg-aqua"}}';

testFunction(testData);

function testFunction(data)
{
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(obj.test2.boxcolor); // bg-white
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Json structure is not correct.

It should be like this- `var testData = '{"test":"testvalue", "test2":{"boxcolor":"bg-white", "iconcolor":"bg-aqua"}}';`

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/bcg41q8b/